# How to correctly set height for the list view

Tags: layout, dart, flutter

I have a column that has 3 children. The third child has a ListView. How do I set the height of the ListView such that it does not overflow the screen. I do not want to calculate the height by subtracting the height of other 2 children from the screen height. I tried LayoutBuilder but the box constraint I get has Infinity as max height (BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity) )

My widget tree looks something like this

```
Container(  //Container A
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
 child:Column(children:[
    TitleWidget(),
    SubtitleWidget(),
    Container( //Container B
      child:ListView(children:getChildren())
    )        
 ])
)
```

The height of the Container A is the screen height. But height of Container B should be Screen height - height of TitleWidget() - height of SubtitleWidget().
If i don't set the height of container B explicitly, I am getting "A RenderFlex overflowed by X pixels on the bottom".

Am I missing something really obvious here?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap you list view with Expanded widget instead of Container widget.

Answer (score 1):

I had a Similar Issue. In my case, I kept the `Container` and in my ListView I added `shrinkWrap: true,` this will shrink the size of the ListView to the total height of all it's children.

And `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` I Specifically don't want the ListView to scroll under the column items, but I want everything to scroll together.